# How to fetch data from another table within a Zend_Db model class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I have two tables `registries` and `names`. Consequently, I have two model classes. I'm coding a method in *registries* model and I need to fetch all names in the *names* table/model. How'd I do it?

Should a simple `new Names()` work? But, is it recommended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's *possible* to create an instance of another table class inside methods of another table class.

But if you have application work to do that involves multiple tables, it's better to design a class that encapsulates that application work, and use both tables from within it.

This is why it's inaccurate to call a table a model.  Nowhere in the `Zend_Db_Table` documentation does it call a table a model.

A model represents some part of your application, and it may involve multiple tables in order to do its work.  A class that corresponds to your table is just a Table.

Decouple your models from your tables!

---

Re your comment:  You're still thinking that a model extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` -- it doesn't!

A model is *not* a data access class, it's a unit of your application.  It doesn't extend any part of the Zend Framework.

The relationship between model and table is *HAS-A*, not *IS-A*.

```
class MyRegistryModel // extends nothing
{
  /**
   * @var Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
   */
  protected $_registryTable;

  /**
   * @var Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
   */
  protected $_namesTable;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_registryTable = new RegistryTable();
    $this->_namesTable = new NamesTable();
  }

  public function getDailyReport()
  {
    // use the tables as needed to build the report
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I work with more than 1 table, then? i can't set $_name = 'table1' and $_name = 'table2'. How would it work?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you have to have your table setup with a dependent relationship

```
registryTable->find(1)->current()->getDependentRowset($namesTable)
```